# Numpy cross-product on rectangular grid

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays holding 2d vectors:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 0.999875,  0.015836],
              [ 0.997443,  0.071463],
              [ 0.686554,  0.727078],
              [ 0.93322 ,  0.359305]])

b = np.array([[ 0.7219  ,  0.691997],
              [ 0.313656,  0.949537],
              [ 0.507926,  0.861401],
              [ 0.818131,  0.575031],
              [ 0.117956,  0.993019]])
```

As you can see, `a.shape` is (4,2) and `b.shape` is (5,2).

Now, I can get the results I want thusly:

```
In [441]: np.array([np.cross(av, bv) for bv in b for av in a]).reshape(5, 4)
Out[441]: 
array([[ 0.680478,  0.638638, -0.049784,  0.386403],
       [ 0.944451,  0.924694,  0.423856,  0.773429],
       [ 0.85325 ,  0.8229  ,  0.222097,  0.621377],
       [ 0.562003,  0.515094, -0.200055,  0.242672],
       [ 0.991027,  0.982051,  0.595998,  0.884323]])
```

My question is: What's a more 'numpythonic' way of getting the above (i.e without the nested list comprehensions)? I've tried every combination of `np.cross()` I can think of, and I usually get results like this:

```
In [438]: np.cross(a, b.T, axisa=1, axisb=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-438-363c0765a7f9> in <module>()
----> 1 np.cross(a, b.T, axisa=1, axisb=0)

D:\users\ae4652t\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.p<snipped>
   1242     if a.shape[0] == 2:
   1243         if (b.shape[0] == 2):
-> 1244             cp = a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]
   1245             if cp.ndim == 0:
   1246                 return cp

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4) (5)
```

Comment: Are you trying to take an inner product? What you are doing is not a cross product.

Comment: I think I'm taking 20 cross-products on a 4 x 5 grid, no? That's the function I'm calling in the list comprehension

Comment: I see what your doing, it probably isnt worth it to optimize this unless these arrays are very large.

Comment: @Ophion: While you are right regarding speed, I +1'd the question because it touches the general subject of how NumPy works, and how it can be used best to speed up array operations.

Comment: @EOL I agree, and I am now very curious to see if there is a way to take all combinations between two array's by row more efficiently then the way I proposed.

Comment: My arrays aren't very large _yet_; just wanted to be ready. That, and any time I see a `for` when I'm using numpy makes me feel a little queasy :-) Thanks for all the answers w/timings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't timed my code, but I am almost certain there is no more *numpythonic* way of doing this than the nice and simple:

```
>>> np.cross(a[None], b[:, None])
array([[ 0.68047849,  0.63863842, -0.0497843 ,  0.38640316],
       [ 0.94445125,  0.92469424,  0.42385605,  0.77342875],
       [ 0.85324981,  0.82290048,  0.22209648,  0.62137629],
       [ 0.5620032 ,  0.51509455, -0.20005522,  0.24267187],
       [ 0.99102692,  0.98205036,  0.59599795,  0.88432301]])
```

[Broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is always the answer...

Comment: Nice; this should be the accepted answer.  Although "always" is a bit of an exaggeration-- there are many cases where broadcasting results in impractically large intermediate arrays.

Comment: Updated my post for timings! As I have never seen the use of [None] before is there any difference between that and reshape(1,-1)?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I **might** suggest `np.newaxis` in place of `None`, but I'm not sure it reads any more clearly. And thanks for the link; I'll bone up again on broadcasting.

Comment: @Ophion I used to always do explicit reshapes, as you suggest, but lately I tend to lean more to slicing with `None`, since it usually allows for more compact code. Which is the same reason I go with `None` over `np.newaxis`.

Answer (score 8):

I thought a bit more on this.

```
>>> a
array([[ 0.999875,  0.015836],
       [ 0.997443,  0.071463],
       [ 0.686554,  0.727078],
       [ 0.93322 ,  0.359305]])
>>> b
array([[ 0.7219  ,  0.691997],
       [ 0.313656,  0.949537],
       [ 0.507926,  0.861401],
       [ 0.818131,  0.575031],
       [ 0.117956,  0.993019]])
>>> c = np.tile(a, (b.shape[0], 1))
>>> d = np.repeat(b, a.shape[0], axis=0)
>>> np.cross(c, d).reshape(5,4)
array([[ 0.68047849,  0.63863842, -0.0497843 ,  0.38640316],
       [ 0.94445125,  0.92469424,  0.42385605,  0.77342875],
       [ 0.85324981,  0.82290048,  0.22209648,  0.62137629],
       [ 0.5620032 ,  0.51509455, -0.20005522,  0.24267187],
       [ 0.99102692,  0.98205036,  0.59599795,  0.88432301]])
```

Some timings:

```
import timeit

s="""
import numpy as np
a=np.random.random(100).reshape(-1, 2)
b=np.random.random(1000).reshape(-1, 2)
"""

ophion="""
np.cross(np.tile(a,(b.shape[0],1)),np.repeat(b,a.shape[0],axis=0))"""

subnivean="""
np.array([np.cross(av, bv) for bv in b for av in a]).reshape(b.shape[0], a.shape[0])"""

DSM="""
np.outer(b[:,1], a[:,0]) - np.outer(b[:,0], a[:,1])"""

Jamie="""
np.cross(a[None], b[:, None, :])"""

h=timeit.timeit(subnivean,setup=s,number=10)
m=timeit.timeit(ophion,setup=s,number=10)
d=timeit.timeit(DSM,setup=s,number=10)
j=timeit.timeit(Jamie,setup=s,number=10)

print "subnivean's method took",h,'seconds.'
print "Ophion's method took",m,'seconds.'
print "DSM's method took",d,'seconds.'

"
subnivean's method took 1.99507117271 seconds.
Ophion's method took 0.0149450302124 seconds.
DSM's method took 0.0040500164032 seconds.
Jamie's method took 0.00390195846558 seconds."
```

For when the length of a=10 and b=100:

```
"
subnivean's method took 0.0217308998108 seconds.
Ophion's method took 0.00046181678772 seconds.
DSM's method took 0.000531911849976 seconds.
Jamie's method took 0.000334024429321 seconds."
```

Hmm you switched the order of the cross product again, both answers are shown if you want (5,4) or (4,5).

Comment: Updated for what you wanted.

Comment: Hey, that's not fair: when timing mine, you're not just testing my solution (using `np.outer`), you're including the `listcomp` line, which is the OP's solution I included only to check the answers..

Comment: Ah, I apologize- updating now.

Comment: That's better. :^)  +1 for including timing code.  [That said, I agree wholeheartedly that it's probably not worth optimizing this unless the OP really needs to.]

Comment: ;) timings are usually the final word in this sort of thing. I really like your answer... great use of outer product!

Comment: +1 for mentioning `numpy.tile` and `numpy.repeat`. DSM's solution is arguably more straightforward, though.